# Magento 1.6.2 SOAP API Errors: Using salesOrderShipmentCreate and continue to get DB integrity violations

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to integrate with the Magento API to create shipments from a fulfillment center's csv file.  I continue to get this error:

```
Caught create exception: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '100000381' for key 2
```

It seems that there is no way around it.  Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
$order  = '100000636';
$carrier = 'fedex';

$proxy = new SoapClient($host.'api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login($user, $pass);

// Create new shipment
try {
    $newShipmentId = $proxy->salesOrderShipmentCreate($sessionId, $order, array('13', '1'), 'shipment comment',false,false);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught create exception: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
var_dump($newShipmentId);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in the `eav_entity_store` table, if the value of `increment_last_id` is smaller than the actual increment ID that was used for the latest successfully created shipment. If so,  try to replace it with the actual last value. Knowing that :

- `entity_type_id` should by default be 8 for shipments, else use the value corresponding to `shipment` in the `eav_entity_type` table,
- If you don't run in single store mode, check the value for the relevant `store_id`.

Comment: That was it.  Updating the `eav_entity_store` `increment_last_id` to where it needed to be.